# Low traffic client synchronization with server in MMO

Tags: mmo, client-server, synchronization

I am implementing MMO where player flies in space on his starship controlling it with arrow keys and cooperate with other players.

I want to implement it so that player will be able to dodge his ship from rocket or something else, so I am trying to predict whole game state on client side using the same world simulating algorithm as server use. That game world is written on C# and will be called within client directly (it's written on Unity3D) and through CLR on C++ server (under Linux). Connection through UDP.

Problem is how to maintain, for example, 1000 players within single map (exclusing all other game objects, mobs...): 
Let's say I will:

- synchronize server with clients 50 times per second
- send to each client states of just that game objects (and players) which he is able to see (within some radius)
- have to send 100 objects to each player within his view radius
- must send averagely 50 bytes per game object (it's id, x,y coords, rotation, state...)

so, it will need to have such network bandwidth: 1000 (clients) * 50 (times per second) * 100 (objects to send to each player) * 50 (bytes per object) = 250 000 000 bytes per second! It's impossible!

Is it possible to reduce this value somehow? For example let clients to fully simulate their game worlds (for a long period of time) and send them just inputs of other clients and synchronize game worlds, let's say, each several seconds but it will cause weird desynchronization issues at leash because of float computations.

Anyway, how such games are programmed in common way? Thank you.

Comment: When sending objects, are you sending the actual object itself (e.g., the image of the space ship, etc.), or just an ID number that refers to the object (which you may already have stored locally somewhere, or download as needed)?

Comment: I send just logical info about objects (world's position, current state (which is one byte) and so on) - no graphics.

Comment: @Slav:  Not wrapping it all up in XML like all the cool kids do these days?  ;-D  Additionally, if the server is smart enough it can send a number of object updates together at once in a single packet, which can help to further reduce network overhead (e.g., ethernet frames).

Comment: No XML of course :) I write integers using B128 compression, use bits shifting and so one - that's how I shrinked pretty much of info about each object into just 50 (averagely) bytes. Raw UDP - no protocols built on it.

Comment: @Slav:  Nice!  All that bit shifting reminds me of my ASM programming days.

Comment: Why not "today days"? :) When I write on AS3, Java, Lua, C# and face such poor performance I miss of C++ and remember about ASM.

Comment: @Slav:  Heheh, I haven't done much ASM recently.  Most things for me are in Java and Perl (mod_perl2 mostly) these days, but I verily enjoy these languages too.

Comment: @Slav, you wrote: "When I write on AS3, Java, Lua, C# and face such poor performance I miss of C++ and remember about ASM". You should learn how to use Lua and C# properly, maybe you'd find the performance less abysmal. Also, complaining about the (allegedly) fastest _scripting_ language out there is at best singular... Is this a game about realtime human genome analysis?

Comment: I use it well. Benchmark tests show that Lua 40 times slower than C++, AS3 50, C# ~50 and so on. And of course we prefer new technologies due to less debugging nights and faster implementation time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You only need about 30 updates (or even less maybe 10 or 20) per second. interpolate the positions of moving objectts client sided.
In general you should only send data when it's REALLY needed.
In WoW you might receive more updates from the players you are in a group with than from the players that are in the same location.
Also, if another player is far away from you, you don't receive as many updates per second about him.

Then, only send one complete snapshot to each player when he connects. After that only send the changes of game objects. If no change occured, don't send it.

Then, make heavy use of BitVectors or howevery you might call them to reduce the amount of unneeded data! Example: You can also try to write a float using only one byte(in a range from 0 to 1 or -1 to 1) so you only have 256 or 128 different values. But the player will not notice any jerky movements thanks to the interpolations.

Look at this for an example with LidgrenLibrary on how to compress data: http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/Optimization

Next: Try to reduce view radius of players as they move, and only transmit important information in that time. Then when they stop increase their view radius again. You can use a spatial hashing system or a bsp tree to reduce the overhead of looking up objects that are "in range".
This is a good read for the topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection

Also compress the data **YOURSELF** only YOU know about the data structure and the temporal coherence in the data (which can and should be exploited).
A general algorithm such as Bzip2, Deflate, whatever, should be used, but only as the final stage of compression!

Also, for non game-critical information, you could also employ additional P2P techniques.
Example: A player plays the "hello" animation.(Just a graphical effect) The player sends this information to the server, but the server doesn't relay the information to the other players. Instead this non-critical effect is send by the player itself to the other clients in range.

EDIT (because of the comment):

Additional methods to decrease the average bit count per second to each player:

1. You wrote that you send "Object did not change". There is no reason to do this.
   If you worry about packet loss (and getting your simulation out of sync because of this) consider the following:
   At each fixed timestep (ex. 100, 200, 300, 400...) hash the simulation state and send it to the server. the server confirms or sends a complete snapshot of all data back.
2. For things like rockets or even players you can employ not only interpolation but also extrapolation in order to make the simulation more realistic.
   Example 'Rocket': Instead of updating with messages like "Is now at position x" just send a message once containing the following: "Rocket Spawned: position(vector), Time(at which simulation step the rocket was spawned), velocity(vector)".
   So you don't even have to include the rotation because the tip will always be in the "velocity" direction.
3. Combine multiple commands in one message and don't ever send messages smaller than 16-20bytes because the udp header will be bigger than the message itself.
   Also don't send packages bigger than the MTU of your protocol because fragmentation will slow down the speed of the transmission.

Comment: Oh, it's a good idea to update some objects more frequently than others, use P2P, degrade floating point accuracy, send just changes (which is not trivial for me because I intended to sync objects periodically but "object did not changed" is the information too). With all of these modifications the whole picture looks more realistic!

Comment: Sending "object did not change" type notices might be a useful technique for testing purposes where you want to see how your game performs when players are on during busy times because it has the potential to put demands on processing as well as the network, but there are yet still better solutions than this (such as creating a stand-alone daemon that controls an actual in-game character, then running that deamon multiple times from different machines).

Answer (score 5):

Few questions first.

Are the 'rockets or something else' intelligent or dumb?  If they're dumb all you need is the timestamp of fire, the origin, and the vector to simulate their path.  If they're intelligent how intelligent are they?  Can you compute at the time of fire that they're going to hit or miss?  If so you can simulate the entire path on the client.  ("At T13 the missile will strike the ship because the play lost the dodge roll / the shooter scored a critical hit.")

In general though there's pretty much no reason to:
 A) have a clock rate of 50Hz, (Most *shooters* get away with 15-20 and MMOs less than that.)
 B) send full state every frame.  (Does the rotation of a missile in space matter at all?  Or can you just assume that it's 'front' is orientated along the vector it's traveling?)

Spend time with prediction and interpolation, and you'll see your bandwidth plummet.  A project I worked on had an update rate of 10Hz, and an object state representation of I think 14 bytes.  (Compress everything you can!  I believe we used 6 bits to define the rotation around the x plane and then another 6 bits for a tilt above/below that plane, it looked indistinguishable from sending an actual rotational matrix / quaternion.)

Another thing you can do is prioritize objects.  Show, maybe there's 100 objects in the relevant set, but do you know his view frustum on the server?  If something isn't in his view can you drop it's update frequency by an order of magnitude?

The general idea isn't to make a perfect simulation on the client, that's impossible, the idea is to make a fun game where the players won't notice that it's not a perfect simulation.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two approaches:

First:
Switch to deterministic physics, send player commands, ai actions, objects coming into view and whatever can't be determined client-side to clients. This must include non-commands, a confirmation that up to a certain point in time nothing but the commands that has been sent and received apply.

The client must run two or three simultaneous simulations.
1: Halts whenever missing data for the next step.
2: Continue using guess data and provide the state used for rendering.
3: Whenever no 1 comes to a halt this simulation copies the state of no 1, catch up to the current time and take over for no 2, which is then dropped.

If the catch up is fast enough you can leave out differing between no 2 and no 3 and just drop the old data immediately.

Second:
Don't use deterministic physics, do the same as above, but send "full frames" once every few seconds. You can easily completely leave out transferring temporary stuff like bullets.

In both cases you might want to be wary about the client predicting anyone dying, it's kinda silly seeing an opponent unexplode.

And +1 for doing the maths, too many people fail to make simple resource use estimates.

Comment: Does "deterministic physics" means that I cannot use floating point values or different simulation steps? I am wondering that critical desynchronization can happen if, e.g., rocket will past by some enemy turret on client but will hit it on server (because of some floating point inaccuracy) which will cause player to keep fighting that turret until next incoming server's synchronization packet (several seconds).

Comment: It means integers and fixed time step. Theoretically you could mock float points to behave, but using integers is way simpler. You have got a point with the missing missile example, if you use non-deterministic physics it's probably best to let the server fully handle death, and transmit cases of death/destruction rapidly.